# Bundling from Github in a Dockerfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, bundler, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to move our Rails app over to a Docker deployment, however I can't manage to get bundle to install from a Github reference.

With the below Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.0-slim

MAINTAINER Chris Jewell <chrisjohnjewell@gmail.com>

# Install dependencies:
# - build-essential: To ensure certain gems can be compiled
# - nodejs: Compile assets
# - libpq-dev: Communicate with postgres through the postgres gem
# - postgresql-client-9.4: In case you want to talk directly to postgres
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y build-essential nodejs libpq-dev postgresql-client-9.4 --fix-missing --no-install-recommends

# Set an environment variable to store where the app is installed to inside
# of the Docker image.
ENV INSTALL_PATH /ventbackend
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

# This sets the context of where commands will be ran in and is documented
# on Docker's website extensively.
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

# Ensure gems are cached and only get updated when they change. This will
# drastically increase build times when your gems do not change.
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
RUN bundle install

# Copy in the application code from your work station at the current directory
# over to the working directory.
COPY . .

# Provide dummy data to Rails so it can pre-compile assets.
RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname SECRET_TOKEN=pickasecuretoken assets:precompile

# Expose a volume so that nginx will be able to read in assets in production.
VOLUME ["$INSTALL_PATH/public"]

# The default command that gets ran will be to start the Unicorn server.
CMD bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
```

I get the following error when trying to run `docker-compose up`:

`You need to install git to be able to use gems from git repositories. For help
installing git, please refer to GitHub's tutorial at
https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git`

I'm assuming that this is because of lines in the Gemfile like:

```
gem 'logstasher', github: 'MarkMurphy/logstasher', ref: 'be3e871385bde7b1897ec2a1831f868a843d8000'
```

However, we also use some private Gems as well.

Is installing Git on the container the way to go? How will this authenticate with Github?

Comment: The error message appears to be very direct in the steps you need to take. Any reason to avoid installing git as it suggests? Most github repos that would be referenced in an installer like this are public, no login needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is installing Git on the container the way to go?

In that case, yes: you can see an example at "[Using Docker to maintain a Ruby gem](http://blog.zedroot.org/using-docker-to-maintain-a-ruby-gem/)". It Dockerfile does include a:

```
# ~~~~ OS Maintenance ~~~~
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

> How will this authenticate with Github?

It does not have to authenticate to GitHub in order to *read*, ie clone.
It you needed to push back a gem (to publish it), *then* you would need for instance your ssh keys (mounted through a volume).
But that is not needed here.

Comment: In this particular case, adding `git-core` to the packages that we `apt-get install` has been fine, however, in some projects we have private repos that we need to bundle also. At this point, where, and how, do we use SSH keys to do so?

Comment: @Knightstick generally, I use a token pass on the build step only through --build-args